# send bulk sms on android sms app using api from another provider

Tags: android, api, sms

I have a bulk sms site http://esmsafrica.com now I am building a sms app that will use the same API so that users registered on the site can still view there balance and send sms, I understand to use default smsmanager for android is below code, I have also searched on android developer page yet nothing seems to help, can someone let me know how to go about this, would I need to import any code from my site? I believe it should look like below code. I have a valid API code, username and password.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, senderID, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```